# React Invalid hook call with Provider even though I don't use hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I've been working on a project for the past couple months no problem, but all of a sudden today I get the following error when I try and boot up my dev server.

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I've done a little bit of digging and think the problem is with my Provider, but I have no idea why because I haven't been using hooks. I've already checked an I am only running 1 react app

App.js

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import {ProtectedRoute} from './components/utils/protected-routes'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import LandingPage from './components/landingPage'
import Index from './components/recipe/main/index'
import Register from './components/register/register'
import ViewRecipe from './components/recipe/view-recipe/index'
import CreateRecipe from './components/recipe/create-recipe/index'
import ResetPassword from './components/account/reset-password/index'
import Discover from './components/recipe/discover/index'

import {Provider} from 'react-redux'; //Wraps everything insider provider
import {store, persistor} from './store';


function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div className="App">
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path ="/" component={LandingPage} />
                <ProtectedRoute path ="/Home" component={Index} />
                <Route path ="/Register" component={Register} />
                <Route path ="/ViewRecipe/:recipeId" component={ViewRecipe} />
                <Route path ="/CreateRecipe" component={CreateRecipe} />
                <Route path ="/EditRecipe" component={CreateRecipe} />
                <Route path ="/ResetPassword" component={ResetPassword} />
                <Route path ="/Discover" component={Discover} />

                <Route  path ="/*" component={() => "Error 404 Page Not Found"} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

store.js

```
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' // defaults to localStorage for web
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)


const store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    //rootReducer, 
    //persistedStorage,
    initialState,
    compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__&& window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
));

const persistor = persistStore(store);

export {store, persistor};
```

Below is the full error in my console

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
    at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1465)
    at useMemo (react.development.js:1520)
    at Provider (Provider.js:10)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17482)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18596)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22154)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22130)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21756)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21188)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:24373)
    at react-dom.development.js:24758
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:21903)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:24757)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:24840)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.1 (register.css?0d8b:45)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
index.js:1 The above error occurred in the <Provider> component:
    in Provider (at App.js:19)
    in App (at src/index.js:10)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:9)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
react-dom.development.js:22665 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
    at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1465)
    at useMemo (react.development.js:1520)
    at Provider (Provider.js:10)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17482)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18596)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22154)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22130)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21756)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21188)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:24373)
    at react-dom.development.js:24758
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:21903)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:24757)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:24840)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.1 (register.css?0d8b:45)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

Comment: So you have verified that both react and react-dom are of same version?

Comment: Yes, both are 16.13.1

Comment: what's at `Provider.js:10`?

Comment: I don't have a provider.js file.

Comment: Hello, for whatever reason I had to uninstall react-redux and re-install.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do two things:

1. First clear cache **`npm cache clear`** or **`npm cache clear --force`**
2. In case you have previous folder **node_modules** named as **node_modules1** not deleted. Delete the **node_modules1** folder.

And start again **`npm start`**.

I hope it resolves the issue.